# Fuelphp input and session issue in model

Tags: fuelphp

I ran into a problem what i cant really solve (i am a begginer with fuelphp).

So when i place input in my model i get this error

```
ErrorException [ Error ]: Class 'Model\Input' not found
```

when i try with session its the same thing

```
ErrorException [ Error ]: Class 'Model\Session' not found
```

And when i try to hardcode a value in it its not inserting, debuged the query no errors. it shows the value is posted (when passing hard code value) but not inserts it in the database.

my code

model

```
namespace Model;
use DB;

    class Event extends \Model {

        static function send_event()
        {
            $query = DB::insert('events');

            $query->set(array(
                'user_id' => Session::get('sentry_user'),
                'event_name' => Input::post('event_name'),
                'event_desc' => Input::post('event_desc'),
                'event_start' => Input::post('event_start'),
                'event_end' => Input::post('event_end'),
            ));
        }

}
```

controller

```
function action_send_data()
{
    $response = Response::forge();
    $val = Validation::forge('events');

    $val->add_field('event_name', 'Esemény neve', 'required');
    $val->add_field('event_desc', 'Esemény leírás', 'required');
    $val->add_field('event_start', 'Esemény kezdődik', 'required');
    $val->add_field('event_end', 'Esemény kejár', 'required');  


    Event::send_event();
    $response->body(json_encode(array(
        'status' => 'ok',
    )));


    return $response;
}
```

could please someone give me a hint what i am doing wrong?

thank you

P.S: in the controller i removed the validation for query debuging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you declare a namespace at the top of a file as you have done with

```
namespace Model;
```

This declares the namespace for all classes called where the namespace is not explicitly defined. For example, your call to Session is actually looking in `Model\Session` when it actually exists in `\Fuel\Core\Session`

There are two ways around this. You've demonstrated an example yourself in your question with a call to the `use` language construct.

```
use DB;
```

This causes PHP to search for classes in this namespace as well as the one which is already being used (Model in this case).

The other way you can do it is by calling the class with the explicit namespace. For example

```
\Fuel\Core\Session::get();
```

Fuel also aliases all core classes to the root namespace for convenience. What this means is you can also directly call classes in `\Fuel\Core` just using `\`. For example

```
\Session::get();
```

Comment: first sorry for the slow reply, and thank you for pointing this out and thanks so much for explaining it, you helped a lot

Comment: Do not "ever" use \Fuel\Core as a namespace. This is an internal framework namespace. If you do then you bypass the alias system, which means core class extensions no longer work.

Comment: @WanWizard, it can still be done if you wish to use the original after the original has been replaced. It's even documented [here](http://docs.fuelphp.com/general/extending_core.html#/extend_and_replace). It may however not be good practice but it's still a plausible use case.